# How to access Active Directory using Identity 2.0 from external site

Tags: active-directory, asp.net-identity, owin

I have a requirement to create a new site that will be a publicly accessible site and use our company's Active Directory to authenticate users.  So, I plan on prompting for a username/password and passing those credentials to our company AD, then creating a claim from the response.  I also would like to use Identity 2.0 to accomplish this.  I see a bunch of examples using Azure AD, but we don't want to mess with that right now.  How can I connect to our Active Directory with no Azure from an external website?

Comment: So, what did you try?

Comment: I haven't gotten it working yet.  I got it working accessing AD internally.  I'm still looking for a tutorial or example accessing AD externally and using the new Identity 2.0 stuff.

Comment: In case anybody comes back to this, I ended up with a server being setup from our sys admin that is open to the outside world, but on our domain.  Setup Federated Authorization on the active directory server and to my application.  Passed necessary information via Claims and implemented my own custom role provider to handle the roles.  This role provider reads the groups the user is a part of from the Claims and those groups are the roles for the user.